# Working with multiple if else statements

Tags: r

I cannot figure out what I need. Here is simplification what I actually need.

I would like to process each function if certain number appears in a vector,
here is example:

```
v <- c(111,88,222,99,555,1,9,6)

if(111 %in% v){
   x <- 111+0.1
 } else if(222 %in% v){
   y <- 222+0.1
 } else if(555 %in% v){
   z <- 555+0.1
 }
```

I would like to process each function if given number is found in vector `v`.

In the above example the `if else` example would give out number `111.1`,`222.1`,`333.1`, what I'm doing wrong here?

Basicaly, I would like to calculate each function if certain number appears in vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `if` check to always be evaluated but once the first one is `true`, the following can never be checked because they are preceded by an `èlse`. Just drop the `else` clauses:

```
v <- c(111,88,222,99,555,1,9,6)

if(111 %in% v){
   x <- 111+0.1
}
if(222 %in% v){
   y <- 222+0.1
}
if(555 %in% v){
   z <- 555+0.1
}
```